# YouTube IFrame player API onStateChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

On `iPhone Safari version 9.3.2` or on `chrome`, when I inspect it to mobile the iframe flashes visible for a moment when I scroll the slider or even when I navigate between different browser tabs, despite the cover image being "on top". 
It seems that the problem is coming from Buffering state, because when I switch tabs and comeback to page it update the value to 3 (buffering) showing the video for a millisecond and then showing back image cover.
Is there a way to avoid it?

React code:

```
 const VideoState = {
   UNSTARTED: -1,
   ENDED: 0,
   PLAYING: 1,
   PAUSED: 2,
   BUFFERING: 3,
   CUED: 5
 };

 this.state = {
   player: null,
   showCover: true,
   videoInitialised: false
 };

onStateChange(event) {
   const { showCover } = this.state;

   if (this.coverTimeout && event.data === VideoState.BUFFERING) {
      window.clearTimeout(this.coverTimeout);
    } 
    if ((event.data === VideoState.PLAYING || event.data === VideoState.BUFFERING) && showCover) {
       this.setState({
         showCover: false
      });
    } else if ((event.data === VideoState.PAUSED || event.data === VideoState.ENDED || event.data === VideoState.UNSTARTED) && !showCover) {
       this.coverTimeout = window.setTimeout(() => {
           this.setState({
            showCover: true
       });
    }, 250);
  }
}
```